# How to assign a the value of a variable from the adjacent cells of another cell in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi so i created a script in sheets to pull a value from a cell everyday but im looking to add another row which shows profit or loss for the day.

```
// Record history from a cell and append to next available row
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy");
    Logger.log(formattedDate);
    var value =sheet.getRange("$c$14").getValue();
    // var profit = ((cell to the left) - (cell above the cell to the left));
    sheet.appendRow([,formattedDate, value, profit]);
}
```

I'm looking to create the variable "profit" by grabbing the value from the cell to the left of the active cell and subtracting the cell above that one (left and up one from the active cell). Any help would be appreciated, thanks

this image shows what i want to be part of the script[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doing some operations with the column letter and the row number:
it is almost your code, except that we have two new variables 
cellLeftValue and cellAboveLeftValue, both of them  calculate the left by using String.fromCharCode  to calculate the left letter:

```js
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy");
    Logger.log(formattedDate);
    var rowIndex = 14;
    var colIdx = 'c' ;
    var leftColIdx = String.fromCharCode(colIdx.charCodeAt(0) - 1);
    var value =sheet.getRange("$" + colIdx + "$" +rowIndex).getValue();
    var cellLeftValue = sheet.getRange("$" + leftColIdx + "$" +rowIndex).getValue();
    var cellAboveLeftValue = sheet.getRange("$" + leftColIdx + "$" + (rowIndex -1)).getValue();
    var profit = cellLeftValue - cellAboveLeftValue ;
    sheet.appendRow([,formattedDate, value, profit]);
}
```

you should add code to validate corner cases.

Comment: hi ive tried this and its almost what i'm looking for, i had to add .getValue() to the cellleftvalue and cellaboveleftvalue to return the values. 

However this is returning the values to the left of my original valuation whereas i am looking for a return of the values to the left of my active cell. So rather than grabbing value from the cell to the left of c14, i would like to grab the value to the left of cell D31 one day, D32 the next day, D33 the next day and so on, so just to the left of the var PROFIT cell. 
I hope that make sense, thanks for the help!